# How to implement Java ESAPI for preventing XSS?

Tags: java, xss, esapi

I've read a lot of posts that **ESAPI for Java** can be used to prevent **XSS** by using **[Validator](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html)** & **[Encoder](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html)**. By the way, I am using Eclipse. I'm not using Maven nor Spring.

My questions are:

1. How to implement Java ESAPI for preventing XSS?
2. Are there other configurations needed aside from adding the ESAPI jar in the *Build Path*?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Updated my answer for question.2

Answer (score 2):

Preventing XSS has some trickery to it.  Validator lets you define input characters to accept/reject.  But there's also the concept of differing contexts, and that's where the Encoder class comes in.  There will be instances in your career where you'll be forced to accept characters as input that can be used to attack a browser.

The basic ESAPI implementation is like this:  reject input characters According to whitelists.  Use the Encoder implementations according to the output contexts... the trick part comes in when making decisions in regards to "Do I encode for HTML first, or for Javascript first?  Either of those can have impacts on your application, and they need to be decided upon based on your application's needs.  I've had applications that required users to input valid Javascript for example... and in those contexts, you need to be very careful.

Answering your part 2:  Yes.  ESAPI as by now you probably know, requires two properties files to be defined... validation.properties, and esapi.properties.  You can compile them into the jarfile yourself (which, would require you to learn maven, so probably not...) or to specify at runtime, java locations, using the standard -Dmy.property syntax.  The loading exceptions actually guide you to the right path.